# Is there a Linux DHCP server that supports assigning different DNS servers to a given host?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dhcp

Is there a DHCP server that runs on Linux which will allow me to configure what DNS servers get assigned to which host?

E.g. If I have 192.168.0.10 and 192.168.0.20 on my network, I'd like to make it so that 192.168.0.10 gets 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2 as its DHCP-assigned DNS servers and 192.168.0.20 will get 3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, if you use the isp-dchpd server you can do something like this:

```
host A {
   hardware ethernet 12:34:56:78:AB:CD;
   fixed-address 102.168.0.10;
   option domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2;
}


host B {
   hardware ethernet 12:34:56:78:EF:CD;
   fixed-address 102.168.0.20;
   option domain-name-servers 3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4;
}
```